# manage.py returns attribute error module has no attribute 'home'

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

i am trying to run manage.py runserver on pycharm and an attribute error is returned

```
 File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Diabetes Prediction\Diabetes_prediction\Diabetes_Prediction\urls.py", line 23, in <mod
ule>
    path("", views.home),
             ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'Diabetes_Prediction.views' has no attribute 'home'
```

I expected the project to run

Comment: Could you share your code ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, Please edit the question to include any necessary source code, data, and error messages as text. Consider [the "needs debugging details" guideline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/417481).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically means that there is no 'home' function or class inside your views module.

To resolve this issue, you should check the Diabetes_Prediction/views.py file and ensure that it contains a function or class named 'home'. Here's a general example of what your views.py might look like:

```
# Diabetes_Prediction/views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

def home(request):
    # Your view logic goes here
    return render(request, 'home.html')  # Adjust the template name as needed
```

Hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You have no Home method or class in `view.py` file. please check properly